# Java getting data from a variable of a class that's the same as the class it's in

Tags: java

I am trying to get data from preRequisite by using my getter method.  When I do, it invokes the toString method and print everything else along with it.  I am trying to get the data just from preRequisite without invoking the toString so that I can compare the data against user's input.  Thank you for your help.

```
public class Course{
   private int units;
   private int number;
   private String name;
   private Course preRequisite;
   private int section;
   private Person instructor;

public Course preReq(){
      return this.preRequisite;
}
```

Comment: No, no where is `toString()` invoked, unless you call `System.outprintln(...)` on the object returned. You're not showing what you do with the preRequisite object after you get it -- and that's likely where your mistake is.

Comment: I am using it like this if (result.preReq().equals("no_preReq")) to do a comparison.  You were right I was using println to output the result that's why it was invoking to the tostring.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood what's happening.  Perhaps you've written something like `System.out.println(myCourse.preReq())` or something similar, in which case `println` has called `toString` from the `Course` class.  Don't panic - `preReq` itself has not called `toString`.

Comment: OK, in answer to your comment, that comparison is most likely never going to return true, because you're trying to compare a `Course` to a `String`.  Perhaps you need something like `result.preReq().toString().equals("no_preReq")` to make sure you compare a `String` to a `String`.

Comment: I tried using result.preReq().toString().equals("no_preReq") and it ended up invoking the toString method and printed everything out within the object.  Its there a way to get the text within preReq object only?

Comment: On reading your question and your code, I have this strong suspicion that you're off course (in a matter of speaking). Why does the Course class hold a Course field? Why is this field supposed to hold prerequisites? It looks like you're trying to fit square pegs into round holes, and then into triangular holes after that. You may wish to re-think the whole thing from the ground up since I suspect that your entire approach may be off.

Comment: It's an assignment and this constraint was given.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `preRequisite` is of type `Course`, but you're treating it as though it were a `String` in `result.preReq().equals("no_preReq")`.

In response to your comment:

> Is there a way to get the text within preReq object only?

If you're looking for a particular value out of the preReq object, like the `name`, you could provide the `Course` class a getter for that since `name` is already a `String` -

```java
public String getCourseName() {
  return this.name;
}
```

Then you can run a similar comparison:

```java
if (result.preReq().getCourseName().equals("no_preReq")) { ... }
```

Of course, this assumes that when a course has ***no*** prerequisite, you've assigned it a `Course` object where `name = "no_preReq";`

One way to avoid this comparison completely would be to leave `preRequisite` as `null` for any `Course` that doesn't have a prerequisite. In that case you can just do a null check.

If you're looking for this information to be provided by `.toString()` then you're going to need to override the `toString()` method for your `Course` class to return just the `String` your looking for, such as `name`.